# missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, html

Why is it come out error with **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

```
docs = dom()
docs += ('<!documenthtml>')
```

Comment: How are you creating an instance of `DOM`?

Comment: You need to pass the name argument on creating an instance: `dom = DOM('myname')`

Comment: after i have creating instance, it still come out error

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because you aren't passing the `name` parameter while creating the class object.

```
class DOM:
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
  def __iadd__(self, other): 
    self.name+=other.name

dom = DOM()
```

Gives-

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

To fix this pass in a value for the name parameter

```
dom = DOM(name = "any value of your choice")
```

Comment: may i ask dom = DOM(name = "any value of your choice"), should initialize  before class DOM?

Comment: Here `dom` is an object of the class `DOM` and can only be created once you have created the class `DOM`. Think of it this way. Apple can be a fruit only when I already know what a fruit actually is. In this analogy, `fruit` is a class and `apple` is that class' object.

Comment: i have added dom = DOM (name ='sdsa') , however it still give same positional error

Comment: What do you mean by this new comment? I don't get you.

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
  
    doc = DOM()
    doc += ('<!DOCTYPE html>')
    
  becoz, the upper part coding should link to this part

Comment: i have added dom = DOM(name = "any value of your choice"), this coding but i run it still come out with error

Comment: Please edit the question itself. That way others could help you too.